# 'Operation not available after Result Set closed'

Tags: java, mysql

I've looked on here for reasons why it would occur and the only thing that I could see would cause that would be because of an open connection. In my code, I close a connection and register a new one to reopen.

```
try{

       //Registration of driver, connector
        String myDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String myURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/maintenance";
        Class.forName(myDriver);
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(myURL, "admin", "");


        //Call MySQL for table names of users
        String query = "SELECT users FROM goods";

        Statement st = connection.createStatement();


        ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(query);

            while (res.next()) {

                String name = res.getString("users");


                if(name.equals(username)){
                    connection.close();
                    res.close();
                          try{
                         Connection connection2;
                         connection2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/maintenance", "admin", "");
                         query = "SELECT idkeys FROM goods";
                         Statement st2;
                         st2 = connection2.createStatement();
                         ResultSet res2;
                         res2 = st2.executeQuery(query);
                         String myDriver2 = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
                         Class.forName(myDriver2);
                         connection2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/maintenance", "admin", "");
                         while (res2.next()) {

                             keyed = res2.getObject("idkeys");

                             if (keyed.equals(sanitizedPass)){
                                 checked = true;
                                 connection2.close();
                                 res2.close();

                             }
                         } 
                    } catch (Exception e2){
                        System.err.println(e2.getMessage());

                    }

                }

  }
  //Close connections  
  if (!checked){
  res.close();
  connection.close();
  }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());  
   }

    return checked;
```

In my code, at least as far as I know, no such thing happens. Why would it still get thrown?

Comment: `connection.close(); res.close();` then you do stuff, but don't break outer loop, so when it loops back to `while (res.next())`, you get error. See line number in error message for exact line causing the error, because it could the the very same issue in your inner loop. Solution: Don't call `close()` manually, use try-with-resources instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    String myURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/maintenance";
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(myURL, "admin", "");

    String query = "SELECT users, idkeys FROM goods";
    Statement st = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(query);

    while (res.next()) {
        String name = res.getString("users");
        if (name.equals(username)) {
            Object keyed = res.getObject("idkeys");
            if (keyed.equals(sanitizedPass)) {
                checked = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
     return checked;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // or do some reasonable error logging
} finally {
    // close the ResultSet, Statement and Connection here
}
```

1. You don't need to create multiple connections; one is enough.
2. Even though you are querying the same table you are sending two different  queries to the database; instead return both fields in the same query (see the query above)